# How to select only products with ids from ids array. MongoDB

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, mongoose, select

I'm getting all products and populate the category with mongoDB.
Also I have array with category ids and I want to get only products, that have that ids in category object.
How to select only this products?

```js
arr of ids [ '615e94cab42d2274f0481232' ]

arr of products [
  {
    _id: new ObjectId("615e945cb42d2274f0481211"),
    image: '',
    category: { _id: new ObjectId("615da90b689b8ef91fa90afd"), name: 'Разное' },
    name: '435пукп',
    type: 'В упаковке',
    piecesPerPackage: 2,
    pricePerPiece: 1,
    pricePerPackage: 2,
    weight: 12,
    description: 'вапвап'
  },
  {
    _id: new ObjectId("615eaa08f68e788c63817641"),
    image: '',
    category: { _id: new ObjectId("615e94cab42d2274f0481232"), name: '2' },
    name: '2',
    type: 'В упаковке',
    piecesPerPackage: 2,
    pricePerPiece: 2,
    pricePerPackage: 2,
    weight: 2,
    description: '2'
  }
]
```

```js
async sortCatalog(arr) {
        const products = await CatalogModel.find().lean()
            .populate("category", "name").select('-__v');
        console.log("arr of ids", arr)
        console.log("arr of products", products)
    }
```

Comment: you could use $lookup and $match after that

Answer (score 0):

Use `category._id` to find it.

```
await CatalogModel.find({'category._id':new ObjectId("615e94cab42d2274f0481232")})
```